# C++ adding item onto a linked list

Tags: c++, class, templates, linked-list

I'm trying to add a node onto the beginning of a linked list (push function).  I'm getting 2 errors:

1) invalid conversion from 'Node int*' to 'int'  (points to **test.Push(&test2);** in main())

2) initializing argument 1 of 'int Linked_List::Push(ItemType) [with ItemType = int]' (points to function push)

I'm really not sure what the problem is. If I remove the & out of **test.Push(&test2);** in main() then I get a lot more errors, so I assume it's correct.

```
//.h
#ifndef Linked_List_h
#define Linked_List_h

template <typename ItemType>
class Node
{
    public:
        ItemType Data;
        Node <ItemType> *next;
};

template <typename ItemType>
class Linked_List
{
        public:
        Node <ItemType> *start;
        Linked_List();
        int Push(ItemType newitem);
};
#endif
```

.

```
//.cpp
#include "Linked_List.h"

template <typename ItemType>
Linked_List <ItemType>::Linked_List(){
    start = NULL;
}

template <typename ItemType>
int Linked_List <ItemType>::Push(const ItemType newitem){    //error
    Node <ItemType> *nnode;  //create new node to store new item
    nnode -> next = start -> next;  //new item now points previous first item of list
    start -> next = nnode;   //'start' pointer now points to the new first item of list
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    Linked_List <int> test;
    Node <int> test2;
    test2.Data = 4;
    test.Push(&test2);  //error
}
```

Comment: first read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) please.

Comment: @Foxic - Your `Linked_List` class uses `int` as the template parameter. Why are you pushing on `Node<int>` pointers? Why is main() even getting involved in using `Node`s at all? Isn't that the responsibility of the Linked_List class to figure out how to create and maintain `Node`s?

Comment: "If I remove the & .. then I get a lot more errors, so I assume it's correct." that's not necessarily true. You are effectively [Programming by Coincidence](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence). Please read up on C++.

Comment: Thanks I got that part to work.  Now can someone tell me why **Node <ItemType> *nnode = new node<ItemType>;** isn't working?  Says error: expected type-specifier before 'node'. Is there another way I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function's signature expects a `ItemType`, which is `int` in your case:

```
int Push(ItemType newitem);
```

But you are trying to pass a `Node<ItemType>`, hence you get an error.

Your `Push` function is already creating a a node internally, so you'd pass the integer directly into it:

```
Linked_List <int> test;
int test2 = 4;
test.Push(test2);
```

I need to point out that your code has several other problems besides that, though - for starters, this snippet:

```
Node <ItemType> *nnode;  //create new node to store new item
```

Does **not** create a Node - it just declares a pointer.

I'd strongly advise you to read up on C++'s basics.

Comment: I guess I commented wrong, it should still work as a linked list though right?

Comment: @Foxic well, it's the responsibility of `Push` and the other functions in your list class to ensure that. A user of your class shouldn't even need to know that there are "nodes" involved.

Answer (score 1):

Push takes the template type, so int in this case.  What you want to do is something like:

```
Linked_List<int> test;
test.push(4);
```

Comment: Now my program just shuts down, "*.exe has stopped working", not sure how to debug so idk if you can help with that

Comment: @Foxic feel free to ask a new question, and mark one of the answers here as accepted if it solved your current problem (compiler error).

Comment: @Foxic - If you write programs like this, you must know how to debug them (not may know, not probably know, but *must* know).  Now is the time to learn how to use your compiler's debugger.  So what compiler are you using?

Comment: Mingw. The problem is with the lines that include a '->' in Push.  I want to add **node = new node<ItemType>** in hopes it'll fix it but it just says **"expected type-specifier before 'node'"** and **"expected ; before 'node'"**

Comment: @Foxic - `I want to add node = new node<ItemType> in hopes it'll fix it` Sounds like you're just throwing stuff at the wall and hoping something sticks.  You can't learn programming, and especially C++ programming, in that fashion.

Comment: My professor does it that way, he showed us how to implement a stack and used that exact line, I'm basically copying him line-for-line.  Either way, I try to see what works and what doesn't because I'm really stumbled here.

Comment: Edit: I was right, it did fix all my problems.  I don't think I was just throwing stuff at the wall, I couldn't just create a lone pointer and adding 'new' helped

Comment: @Foxic don't forget to delete the pointer somewhere..